# Getting started creating a web form in Microsoft Teams

Tags: api, microsoft-teams

I dont know where to begin.  Do I need to create an app? Do I need to use bots?  I have tried finding docs online but don't know where to start.  Any help with be appreciated.

I am trying to create a small form in a teams channel that my users will fill out.

User enters @projects

Web server responds with

[image]

User clicks submit and data gets posted to my web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that there are a few different kinds of applications in Teams, so finding the one that suits your needs can be a little confusing at first. For what you're trying to do, I would recommend a Bot, and when it received a message (which it will do when it receives your @mention), it can respond with an Adaptive Cards. Adaptive Cards, if you've not used them, are like small embedded forms inside the chat. The user can complete the card and click a button, and it will send the payload back to your bot to do whatever it needs.

Bots, incidentally, are basically just web services, so your bot can do whatever it needs once it received the payload, such as calling another API in turn.

You haven't mentioned what language you might want to work in, but here are some good starting point nevertheless:

- https://dev.botframework.com/
- https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples
- https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot (I've linked the C# version - you should know that Teams bots use the same Microsoft framework as -all- bots build for the Microsoft world, such as web chat bot or a Skype bot. As a result, you have to ensure that anything you look at is applicable to Teams as some content/samples are not)
- https://adaptivecards.io/ (as with Bots, Adaptive Cards have a life outside of Teams, so some articles/content/etc. might not be applicable to your scenario)

Comment: Awesome.. thanks a ton.  the web service will be in php.  very simple call->form->submit->response type setup.  I assume I can then reply back to the form payload with a "good job, you submitted time" type thing.   thanks agian

Comment: sounds good and yes you can definitely send a reply - standard bot behavior to do that.